# Can you access chatter Poll choices or poll votes?

Tags: chatter

When you create a chatter poll you create the poll choices separately so these are most likely a separate Sobject.

Is there any way to access either the choices in the poll or the votes for a particular choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Poll votes are not currently exposed and most likely never will be since if these objects were exposed there would be no way to keep the votes anonymous. See this [idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jTFmAAM) for the option to create polls with public vs. private votes.

Poll choices are stored in the FeedPollChoice Sobject. However, this is only accessible through the chatter REST api. You can't even get describe information for this object through apex or the metadata api.

Comment: How exactly do you access the FeedPollChoice sobject? I can't seem to find it anywhere...

Comment: There is now a FeedPollVote sObject that administrators can use to see who voted for which choice: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedpollvote.htm

Answer (score 3):

If you use the new Chatter in Apex feature (formerly "Connect in Apex") that is available in dev preview in Spring 13 and is expected to GA in Summer 13 you can:

- **post feed polls**: ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(community id, feed type, subject id, FeedItemInput including poll info, null)
- **get information about polls (choices and results, not individual votes)**: ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedPoll(community id, feed item id) / ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItem(community id, feed item id)
- **vote on polls**: ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.voteOnFeedPoll(community id, feed item id, choice id)

Spring 13 dev preview doc is in here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need an automated way to get the results, you can simply access them in the database, via the Developer Console for instance. Get your desired FeedPollChoice entries by the FeedItemId corresponding to the FeedItem that represents your question. Then link each FeedPollChoice to all the FeedPollVotes by ChoiceId. FeedPollVote.CreatedById is the ID of the user who submitted the vote, so you can link that to the User table to get names.