# Can we insert both object record via any way FeedPollChoice and FeedPollVote?

Tags: community, chatter, lightning-community, chatter-feed

Can we insert both object record via any way FeedPollChoice and FeedPollVote?
Using Connect.API Or normal apex.

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation,the only supported calls for [FeedpollChoice](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedpollchoice.htm) and [FeedPollVote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feedpollvote.htm) are describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve()

Even,tools like Dataloader, Workbench do not support an operation like Insert on these objects
[image]

As mentioned in the [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5920/can-you-access-chatter-poll-choices-or-poll-votes) ,Poll votes are not currently exposed and most likely never will be since if these objects were exposed there would be no way to keep the votes anonymous.